# "processAxisFault() found a null HTTP status" and the program execution stops

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-axis, tomcat9

After a launching a service on Apache Tomcat 9.0.52 and Axis2 1.8.0 I've got the following error. After this error, nothing happens, just full stop. Where to dig to find the roots of the problem? How to fix it?
`ERROR org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet - processAxisFault() found a null HTTP status from the MessageContext instance, setting HttpServletResponse status to: axis2.http.response.state`

Comment: Please take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with one particular `ear` file (while all other `ear` files worked perfectly) with Tomcat9.

It turned out that in that particular project `xml-resources/META-INF/services.xml` file (in my glassfish with axis2 IDE) had an old URL: `"http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only"` while all my other `aar` files had the correct URL `"http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only"`.

Once I updated the `services.xml` file, the problem got resolved.